# Animate adding height constraint to keyboard extension view

Tags: ios, autolayout, ios-autolayout, ios-keyboard-extension

In my keyboard extension, there is one particular viewController which I would like to cause the keyboard to increase in height. Before presenting this viewController, the main UIInputViewController calls this method on itself, passing a value of 400.0:

```
- (void)setKeyboardHeight:(CGFloat)height {
    if (self.heightConstraint) {
        [self.view removeConstraint:self.heightConstraint];
        self.heightConstraint = nil;
   }

    self.heightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0 constant:height];

    [self.view addConstraint:self.heightConstraint];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}
```

The height of the keyboard does change to the specified value, but it isn't animated. Is this impossible to accomplish, or am I just using the wrong method in a keyboard extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one solution I came up with. Call `animateKeyboardHeightTo: speed:` and pass in the height you want the keyboard to change to as `targetHeight` and the number of points per ms as `speed`, and the keyboard will increase or decrease to the specified height. I tried to use duration rather than speed, increase by one point per iteration and calculate the duration for `dispatch_after` so that the whole animation would occur within the specified duration, but I couldn't get `dispatch_after` to execute fast enough. I don't know if it is simply not sufficiently precise, or if it cannot execute at less than 1 second intervals, but this was the only solution I could come up with.

If you want to toggle between sizes, you can store `self.view.frame.size.height` in a property before making the initial call to `animateKeyboardHeightTo: speed:`, and then call this method again and pass in the stored height to restore the keyboard to its initial height.

```
- (void)animateKeyboardHeightTo:(CGFloat)targetHeight speed:(CGFloat)speed {
    CGFloat initialHeight = self.view.frame.size.height;

    if (targetHeight < initialHeight) {
        speed = -speed;
    }
    [self setKeyboardHeight:initialHeight];
    [self increaseKeyboardHeightToTargetHeight:targetHeight speed:speed];
}

- (void)increaseKeyboardHeightToTargetHeight:(CGFloat)targetHeight speed:(CGFloat)speed {
    CGFloat currentHeight = self.heightConstraint.constant;
    CGFloat nextHeight = currentHeight + speed;
    if ((speed > 0 && nextHeight > targetHeight) || (speed < 0 && nextHeight < targetHeight)) {
        nextHeight = targetHeight;
    }
    [self setKeyboardHeight:nextHeight];

    if ((speed > 0 && nextHeight < targetHeight) || (speed < 0 && nextHeight > targetHeight)) {
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(1 * NSEC_PER_MSEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self increaseKeyboardHeightToTargetHeight:targetHeight speed:speed];
        });
    }
}

- (void)setKeyboardHeight:(CGFloat)height {
    [self removeHeightConstraint];
    [self addHeightConstraintWithHeight:height];
}

- (void)removeHeightConstraint {
    if (self.heightConstraint) {
        [self.view removeConstraint:self.heightConstraint];
        self.heightConstraint = nil;
    }
}

- (void)addHeightConstraintWithHeight:(CGFloat)height {
    self.heightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0 constant:height];

    [self.view addConstraint:self.heightConstraint];
}
```